# set onClick function to Vscode extension decoration

Tags: typescript, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to trigger a function when clicking vscode decoration[image]

so I created a decoration for each async match
this is my decoration :

```
  const decoration = {
    range,
    hoverMessage: `${command} ${input}`,
    command: {
      title: 'Run Function',
      command: 'run-function.playFunction',
      arguments: [editor.document.fileName, funcNameMatches?.[1]]
    }
  };

  decorations.push(decoration);
```

this is example I got from gpt, but in the vscode library I don't see that decoration has a command attribute and it doesn't react, any solution/ workaround will be helpful
I tried to figure out what they have done here https://github.com/jest-community/vscode-jest/tree/master but I got lost

Comment: Hovers can take a command link.  Perhaps that can be of use.

Comment: Including hovers on decorations.  Let me know if you want to know more.  You can't click directly on the decoration, but would have to hover over the decoration and then clickable commands can be added to that hover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, decorations has no `onClick` event, unfortunatelly.

What you are seeing in that Jest Test extension is related to the Test API, which provides an icon in the gutter, that supports clicks, but only related to the Test API itself.

If you need some kind of interaction, I suppose you should look for the Action Providers (https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/programmatic-language-features#possible-actions-on-errors-or-warnings) or Code Lens (https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/programmatic-language-features#codelens-show-actionable-context-information-within-source-code) instead.

Hope this helps